# VMware Workstation 11.1.2 Ubuntu Guest Menu bar and menu blurred of Black When 3D Acceleration is enabled

Tags: unity, graphics, vmware, 3d

I am experiencing a problem with the menu bar being blurred.

I can navigate using terminal and can open apps using terminal. When I disable 3D acceleration I have the menu bar but I have performance Issues whereas with 3D acceleration enabled there is no performance issues. I ran this command in terminal `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` and it came back with a yes for everything including Unity 3D supported.

Hi there, I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and here is a link to the pics. dropbox.com/sh/wvzdjrdwzq01qb0/AACtaudNvHJdU0c3dPM8-VGWa?dl=0 –

If anyone has found a fix please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: You can still include links to images in your question. A more reputable member may then embed the image into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What 3D hardware you have?  Which the host/slave OS is? Please [edit] your question and add this information... Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: Hi there, I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and here is a link to the pics. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wvzdjrdwzq01qb0/AACtaudNvHJdU0c3dPM8-VGWa?dl=0